# Pin RDP Icon to start menu Windows 8

Tags: remote-desktop

I've got a custom RDP icon on my desktop, how can I pin this to the start menu?  There is no option to pin to start in the context menu for RDP icons.

Comment: By Icon, do you mean a Shortcut or an executable?

Answer (score 10):

The only way I know of doing this by creating a shortcut to mstsc.exe and providing your existing .rdp file as a parameter to the command line.

From http://www.jenovarain.com/2013/02/pin-rdp-shortcut-to-start-screen/

```
%windir%\system32\mstsc.exe "C:\Path\To\My\RDF File.RDP"
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Right-click on **%windir%\system32\mstsc.exe** and select **"Pin to Start Menu".**
2. Right-click on **"Remote Desktop Connection"** shortcut you just added to Start Menu and rename it and add path to your .rdp file to **Target** as a parameter (e.g. C:\Windows\System32\mstsc.exe c:\myserver.rdp)

You can also just leave the shortcut as "Remote Desktop Connection", right-click the shortcut, and pin the .rdp to the top of the list for this application.